# In AWS CDK how can I tell, in app.py, if its a deploy or destroy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

In AWS CDK how can I tell, in app.py, if its a deploy or destroy?

I'm wanting to set a variable with the lifecycle action, whether its deploy, destroy, synth, etc, when a CDK stack is deployed.

Ex.

```
cdk deploy --all
```

And then use that variable in my code.

It does not appear app.py can get an argv variable, and this doesn't seem to be part of the environment variables.

Does anyone know how this might be accomplished?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? If it's for something like logging, maybe you can create a script that calls cdk and log there?

Comment: My use case is that certain context parameters are required to deploy a stack, but not to destroy it. So when I validate the context parameters I need to know which action is taking place.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around in the debugger I cannot see a way to identify this.

Could you perhaps use a parameter to get this?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/parameters.html

```
cdk deploy YourStack --parameters cmd_type=deploy
```

I know it's not perfect because it can be skipped or missed but perhaps it would help in a pipeline since that's fixed?

Perhaps you can explain more about what you are trying to achieve and why you need those details?

Comment: i have the same problem, A use case is you want to deploy a big zip file on a S3, cdk fails every time, so kowning if deploy destroy i can clear the s3 so it can be destroyed or i can upload the files because i am deploying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use context values also, say:

```
npx --no-install cdk destroy -c destroy=true --require-approval=never
```

And then retrieve it in the app

```
is_destroy = app.node.try_get_context("destroy")
```

A use case for this need for me was, when deploying a lambda package via CDK, I did not had handle to the the package name in the un-deployment though I need it always in the deployment step